# Problemas con ajax ,condigo de error: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy teniendo problemas desde hace poco con esta llamada **ajax**, siempre he ejecutado el mismo proceso en mis **ajax** pero últimamente estoy confrontando este error:

> Unexpected end of JSON input

Este es mi archivo **html**

```
 <ul class="vote-container">
   <li id="vote-up"><span data-id="<?php echo$id[2];?>" class="vote vote-up" id="<?php echo$id[2];?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span></li>
    <li id="vote-count"><span data-id="<?php echo$id[2];?>" class="vote-count" id="<?php echo$id[2];?>">0</span></li>
   <li id="vote-down"><span data-id="<?php echo$id[2];?>"  class="vote vote-down" id="<?php echo$id[2];?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></li>
  </ul>
```

Este es mi archivo **ajax**

```
$(function(){
    $(".vote-container li ").click(function(e){

        var vote=$(this).attr("id")
        var vote_id=$("."+vote).data("id");
        e.preventDefault();
        var url="/ajax/votacion_denunciantes.php";

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:"POST",
            data:{vote:vote,vote_id:vote_id},
            dataType:"json",
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        }).done(function(response){

         console.log(response);

        }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

            if( console && console.log ) {
                console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
                console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  errorThrown);
            }         
        }) 
     })
```

la salida por la consola es

> Unexpected end of JSON input

No creo que sea necesario publicar el archivo php ya que el error lo esta provocando el mismo **ajax**, alguien puede darme una mano please?

Comment: `var vote=$(this).attr("id")` falta `;` en esta linea

Comment: no creo que un punto y coma sea el error pana ya que se trata de `javascript`

Comment: probé y solo agregue esto `})` al final y funciona

Comment: Ya viste si el Json que mandas tiene el formato correcto?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema lo tienes a la hora de montar tu *data* en la llamada `Ajax`.

Trata de ajustar tu código de esta manera:

```
 $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:"POST",
        data:{"vote":vote,"vote_id":vote_id},//Aquí es donde he realizado el cambio
        dataType:"json",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 }).done(function(response)
```

Te faltaba poner las *comillas* a los parámetros.

**EDIT**

Revisando de nuevo tu código creo que lo que tienes mal es cerrar bien tu `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:"POST",
        data:{"vote":vote,"vote_id":vote_id},
        dataType:"json",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    }).done(function(response){

       console.log(response);

        }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

           if( console && console.log ) {
                console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
                console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  errorThrown);
           }         
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: lo hice asi y tampoco funciono '

Comment: el punto y coma no es problema ya que se trata de `javascript`

Comment: Sabes en qué línea te marca ese error?

Comment: no del todo el error lo señala en el fail por la consola es decir que no tengo idea de donde esta el error exacrtamente

Comment: ey acabo de probar el codigo en mozilla firefox y funciona a la perfeccion , no entiendo por que no esta funcionando en chrome. alguna idea amigos?

Comment: Te dejo un enlace, quizás te pueda servir. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79237/jquery-ajax-no-funciona-en-chrome-pero-si-funciona-en-firefox

Comment: Gracias amigo !

Comment: Las comillas no tienen que ver, puede escribir su parámetro así: `data:{vote:vote, vote_id:vote_id},` Si dices que funciona en un navegador y en otro no, prueba a limpiar la caché de ese navegador, porque es casi seguro que es un problema de caché o algo así, @andygibbs

Comment: `CTR+F5` Puedes limpiar la cache